# How to Open PWA programatically?

Tags: javascript, redirect, callback, progressive-web-apps

My point of sale software uses the Square Point of Sale API. Basically I click an Android intent: link and open Square, accept payment, then Square redirects back to a callback URL of my choice.

Despite the `start_url` and `standalone` being defined and the PWA being installed, when Square calls for the callback URL Chrome still opens the site in the browser, NOT standalone.

So I tried a workaround for this. I set the callback URL to a blank page with a single anchor. Then wrote a simple script that would click a link to take me to the PWA. `.click()` does not work unfortunately though, and still opens the page in the browser.

Only manually clicking the link will trigger the PWA.

Is there any workaround to this? Or do PWAs/webAPKs simply must be launched by user action?

Is there a chrome://flag or setting to always force an installed standalone PWA to open on Android?